# send data from activity to fragment android studio

Tags: android, android-fragments, bundle

I want to send data from activity to fragment, but in fragment data submitted by me is null. I don't know why. this is code when I'm send data and call the fragment.

```
String b = "hahhaha";
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("coba" ,b);
bundle.putSerializable("modelassign" ,modelAssign);

// set Fragmentclass Arguments
ViewTaskFragment vtf = new ViewTaskFragment();
vtf.setArguments(bundle);

//call fragment
FragmentTransaction transact=getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transact.add(R.id.content_frame, new ViewTaskFragment(), "viewtaskfragment");
transact.commit();
```

and this is code when I'm retrieve the data are sent:

```
 modelAssign = (ModelAssign) this.getArguments().getSerializable("modelassign");
 String haha = this.getArguments().getString("coba");
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

while adding fragment to transaction, you are creating new instance of `ViewTaskFragment()`, use already created object in which you have stored bundle.

```
transact.add(R.id.content_frame, vtf  , "viewtaskfragment");
```

Comment: waw.. it is very helpful thanks

Answer (score 1):

You're passing the arguments bundle into a `Fragment`:

```
ViewTaskFragment vtf = new ViewTaskFragment();
vtf.setArguments(bundle);
```

but then creating a new `Fragment` for the transaction:

```
transact.add(R.id.content_frame, new ViewTaskFragment(), "viewtaskfragment");
```

Use the `Fragment` you've previously created that contains the arguments:

```
transact.add(R.id.content_frame, vtf, "viewtaskfragment");
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
transact.add(R.id.content_frame, new ViewTaskFragment(), "viewtaskfragment");
```

to

```
transact.add(R.id.content_frame, vtf, "viewtaskfragment");
```