# How to send a string data from activity to fragment

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to send a string data from activity to a fragment, but it always giving error. 
I checked the links below and tried them, but still same.

[send data from activity to fragment android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38992070/send-data-from-activity-to-fragment-android-studio)
[Send data from activity to fragment in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12739909/send-data-from-activity-to-fragment-in-android)

My code is like below, myActivity.kt  (I didn't delete the comment lines, I also tried them too)

```
img_foto1.setOnClickListener {

        val bundle = Bundle()
        bundle.putString("imgviewname", "img_foto1")
        val fraginfo = adsCameraOrGallery()
        fraginfo.arguments = bundle

        //val imgviewBundle = Bundle()
        //imgviewBundle.putString("coba", "img_foto1")
        //imgviewBundle.putSerializable("modelassign", "test")
        //val fragmentObj = adsCameraOrGallery()
        //fragmentObj.setArguments(imgviewBundle)

        //val transactionData: FragmentTransaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        //transactionData.add(0, fragmentObj, "viewtaskfragment")
        //transactionData.commit()

        //val transactionData: FragmentTransaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        //transactionData.add(0, fraginfo, "viewtaskfragment")

        //transactionData.commit()


        var dialog = adsCameraOrGallery()
        dialog.show(supportFragmentManager,"Choose photo")

    }
```

Fragment class is like below;

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {


    var args : Bundle = Bundle()
    var dataFromActivity = args.getBundle("imgviewname")
    var temp = args.getString("imgviewname")

    //comingData = this!!.arguments!!.getString("imgviewname")
             }
```

So from the fragment, both of the lines' data above is null. There is no data coming from the activity.

If I use the line below, in the fragment, this time I'm receving "KotlinNullPointerException" error.

```
ComingDataFromActivity = this!!.arguments!!.getString("imgviewname")
```

How can I do that?
Thanks.

---

Regarding to @Mike's suggestions, these lines belove worked for me, updating the post.

Activity;

```
img_foto1.setOnClickListener {

        val bundle = Bundle()
        bundle.putString("imgviewname", "img_foto1")
        val fraginfo = adsCameraOrGallery()
        fraginfo.arguments = bundle

        var dialog = adsCameraOrGallery()
        dialog.arguments =bundle

        dialog.show(supportFragmentManager,"Choose foto")
    }
```

Fragment;

```
    var comingData = this!!.arguments!!.getString("imgviewname")
```

Comment: In your first snippet, the `dialog` that you show is not the one you set the arguments on earlier, `fraginfo`. Either `show()` `fraginfo`, or change that to set the arguments on `dialog`. The second block isn't correct, because you're creating a new, empty `Bundle` there, not retrieving the arguments. You've got the right idea in your last block, but just make sure to correct the first one, setting the arguments on the right `Fragment` instance.

Comment: Many thanks @Mike , your suggestions solved the problem. I'm adding the working codes to my original post.

Answer (score 0):

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("key", "test");
// set Fragmentclass Arguments
Fragmentclass fragobj = new Fragmentclass();
fragobj.setArguments(bundle);
```

and in Fragment onCreateView method:

```
String strtext = getArguments().getString("key");
```

Comment: unfortunately didn't worked, throw "KotlinNullPointerException" error at "String strtext = getArguments().getString("key")"  line.

Comment: try this 
        arguments?.let {
            String strtext = it.getString("key", "")
      
        }

Comment: Couldn't convert this code to Kotlin, also Android Studio too. I don't get it where should I add this argument?

Comment: in your fragment

Comment: I put under onCreateView this code ".let { String strtext = it.getString("key", "") }", but it gives error. "Expecting an element".  Sorry I'm beginner at Android programming.

Comment: you can also declare a public method in your activity that returns a string type and you can access it directly in your fragment.

Comment: Exemple in your activity

var image="url" 

fun getMyData():String{
return image
}

and in your fragment 

@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        var myDataFromActivity = activity.getMyData();
        return view;
    }

Comment: Now I see, but the problem is, if I put this method in root of my activity class, that works, I can call from the fragment. But I need to call this method inside "img_foto1.setOnClickListener", so if I put inside this listener, it isn't working. I mean I can't call this method from the fragment. Or I don't know how to call from the fragment, if it's possible?

Comment: gives the value of the string in the imagefo.setOnClickListener{ image="new string"}

Comment: But I can't put any parameter to the onClickListener method like this "img_foto1.setOnClickListener(image:String)" . Also tried with parameter like you wrote. But it throws "none of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied " error.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use interface for accessing data.
In class where you want to use data

```
class A implement PassDataListener{
String str=null;
//PASS CONTEXT TO OF LISTENER TO CLASS WHERE YOU WANT TO GET DATA
B b=new B(A.this);

@override
public void getString(String text){
this.str=text;
}
}
```

```
interface PassDataListener{
void getString(String a);
}
```

```
class B{
PassDataListener listener;
public(PassDataListener passDataListener){
this.listener=passDataListener;
}
//PASSING DATA TO CLASS WHERE YOU THIS DATA
String text="abc";
listener.getText(text);
}
```

Comment: I already using an interface for sending data from fragment to activity. For the opposite side, should I create another interface? I'll try, but isn't bundle kinda easy way?

Comment: Using dialog.show it will show in popup where as intent will pass data to another activity/Fragment and it self also means activity to fragment or vise-versa. and there is no connection between dialog and intent. I think instead of using dialog intent will help you to achieve your goal.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, will try intent method too. But if I use intent, I can't popup the fragment like a window in activity, right? I mean if I use intent, it will be completely new full screen fragment, not like dialog?

Answer (score 0):

In your Activity:-

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), SearchContact.class);
 Bundle a = new Bundle();
        a.putString("key", "text");
        intent.putExtra("model1", a);
        startActivity(intent);
```

In your Fragment:-

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
Bundle bundle = intent.getString("model1");
```

Try this may be it will help you.

Comment: I'm already using "dialog.show(supportFragmentManager,"Choose photo")" in my "img_foto1.setOnClickListener" so I'm not sure if I can use another intent method? It throws some ActivityNotFoundException errors.

Answer (score 0):

In your Activity,

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
 String text = "Here is my text";
 bundle.putString("text", text );
 FragmentClass fragment = new FragmentClass();
 fragment.setArguments(bundle);
 transaction.replace(R.id.fragment, fragment);
 transaction.commit();
```

In your Fragment

```
@Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    String myText = this.getArguments().getString("text");

 }
```

Comment: I tried to convert activity code to Kotlin, but Android Studio couldn't convert "transaction" class. It throws "unresolved reference" error.

Comment: @sleepy refer dis ``` https://stackoverflow.com/a/53965039/12273964 ```